# JQUERY image overlay fadeIn() fades in and out when mouseover

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am looking to get a nice smooth rollover image to fadeIn over the parent image for a set of buttons.

I have my overlay image stacked ontop of my main image, and it's set to "display: none;".

I have the following jQuery, and it works to FadeIn the overlay image, but it fades it in and out repeatedly when the mouse is over the image. Do I have something wrong in the syntax for my jQuery?  Thanks in advance.

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery(document).ready(function() {
        jQuery(".main").mouseenter(function() {
            jQuery(".overlay").fadeIn();
        });

        jQuery(".main").mouseleave(function() {
            jQuery(".overlay").fadeOut();
        });
    }); 

 </script>
```

and my HTML code:

```
<style type="text/css">
<!--
   .hoverbox { position: relative; }
   .main { width: 243px; height: 117px; }
   .overlay { position: absolute; width: 243px; height: 117px; top: 0; left: 0; display: none; }
-->
</style>

    <!-- button 1 -->
    <div class="hoverbox" style="float: left; width: 243px; height: 117px;">
        <a href="/locations/sacramento-international-airport/">
            <img class="main" src="/images/home-button-smf_orig.jpg" />
            <img class="overlay" src="/images/home-button-smf_rollover.jpg" />
        </a>
    </div>
    <!-- end button 1 -->
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this instead:

```
<script>

$(document).ready(function() {

    $(".hoverbox").on("mouseenter", function(){

        $(".overlay").stop(true, true).fadeIn();

    });

    $(".hoverbox").on("mouseleave", function(){

        $(".overlay").stop(true, true).fadeOut();

    });

}); 

</script>
```

I think hovering over the image itself was a bad idea, here I use the parent container. Also, using the on() method is now the preferred way to trigger mouse enter and leave events.

Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

css is enough in this case, try the below code

```
.main:hover + .overlay{ display:block; }
```

and make sure overlay has a higher z-index

```
.overlay { 
      position: absolute; width: 243px; height: 117px; 
      top: 0; left: 0; display: none; z-index: 2;
 }
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Grhqn/1/

for graceful fading

```
 .overlay {
    position: absolute; width: 243px;  height: 117px;   top: 0;
    left: 0;   z-index: 2;   transition: opacity 1.5s ease;  opacity:0;
}

.overlay:hover {  opacity:1;  }
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Grhqn/3/

Comment: Thanks but I need a graceful FadeIn on it, I don't think that is possible with the CSS above?

Comment: @916Networks It is possible using `transition`, you can check out my updated answer

Answer (score 1):

Michael's answer is a good one and will work, but it may be preferable to use [CSS transitions](http://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/t/transition/) for the animation and reserve jQuery for the behavior.

Here's a [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/JJcQv/2/).

JavaScript

```
$(".hoverbox")
    .mouseenter(function () {
        $(this).addClass("on");
    })
    .mouseleave(function () {
        $(this).removeClass("on");
    });
```

CSS

```
.overlay {
    opacity: 0;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    -webkit-transition: .4s;
    -moz-transition: .4s;
    -o-transition: .4s;
    -transition: .4s;
}

.hoverbox.on .overlay {
    opacity: 1;
}
```

Here's a [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/JJcQv/) of the former approach (similar to Michael's answer). Also, your CSS has been cleaned up for both examples.

Comment: Interesting, thank you for posting.  Will the above method work for IE8/9?

Comment: As is, the code will not work in any version of IE before 10. That said, there are solutions that let you use the more modern CSS transition approach, while still supporting older versions of IE. For that, I would suggest looking at [Modernizr](http://modernizr.com/docs/).

Comment: Oh cool, I have not seen Modernizr yet.  Thanks for sharing and I'll check it out.